# Is it possible to edit and write an existing PDF file?

Tags: php, pdf

Is there a way in PHP to read an existing PDF file and protect it with a string that has Example Demo written on it,
Similar to what the shutterstock site does to its images for those who do not pay for the download image?

Comment: The best way to do this is with a library. Consider using mPDF, it's amazing. Example code could be found here: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setsourcefile.html.

It might however be easier to simple serve two pdf files, one with a watermark, one without. PDF manipulation could be expensive to do in real time and it takes a lot more code to pull off.